# Sql query to segregate values from 3 tables based on one column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables and the result table should have columns from all three tables based on the column `user_id` of first table.

[image]

Comment: Please format your question properly to have more readability.

Comment: Oracle or Mysql? And why are there 2 users with same user_id(10)?

Comment: MYSQL.. sorry you may consider for single time

Comment: Your data looks dodgy and this is a basic join operation. If you know what a JOIN is then you probably know how to do this already. If you don't know what a JOIN is then an explanation will likely be meaningless. You probably need to take a look at a basic SQL tutorial first.

Comment: @BriteSponge here the 3 column(user_id,u_id,usr_id) must be equal and have to fetch the values from 3 tables. i know can be done using by join,but i am not getting required output

Comment: I'm not surprised, you have 2 user_id = 10 - is that correct in your data , if so there is no way to get the result you want.

Comment: @P.Salmon no,user_id = 10 occurs only once.. you where right.. please help to query it.   thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 10,john should be 15,john this looks like a very simple join. If the below model is incorrect please copy it, edit it and add to your question.

```
drop table if exists t1,t2,t3;

create table t1(u_id int, name varchar(10), prd int);
create table t2(u_id int, temp int);
create table t3(u_id int, Office int);

insert into t1 values (10,'ram',1), (15,'john',1),(20,'sat',1),(12,'peter',1);
insert into t2 values (10,32),(20,42),(15,25),(12,32);
insert into t3 values (20,56),(10,57),(15,56),(12,57);
```

This query

```
select t1.*,t2.*,t3.*
from t1
join t2 on t2.u_id = t1.u_id
join t3 on t3.U_id = t1.u_id
order by t1.u_id;
```

Produces this result

```
+------+-------+------+------+------+------+--------+
| u_id | name  | prd  | u_id | temp | u_id | Office |
+------+-------+------+------+------+------+--------+
|   10 | ram   |    1 |   10 |   32 |   10 |     57 |
|   12 | peter |    1 |   12 |   32 |   12 |     57 |
|   15 | john  |    1 |   15 |   25 |   15 |     56 |
|   20 | sat   |    1 |   20 |   42 |   20 |     56 |
+------+-------+------+------+------+------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If the model looks like this

```
drop table if exists t1,t2,t3;

create table t1(u_id int, name varchar(10), prd int);
create table t2(u_id int, temp int);
create table t3(u_id int, Office int);

insert into t1 values (10,'ram',1), (15,'john',1),(20,'sat',1),(12,'peter',1);
insert into t2 values (10,32),(20,42),(10,25),(12,32);
insert into t3 values (20,56),(10,57),(10,60),(10,56),(12,57);
```

You may need to simulate a full join

```
select t1.u_id,t1.name,t2temp,t3office
from t1
join
(
select t2.u_id as t2id, t2.temp as t2temp, t3.u_id as t3uid,t3.office as t3office 
from
(
select t2.*,if(t2.u_id <> @p ,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,@p:=t2.u_id from t2 ,(select @rn:=0,@p:=0) rn order by t2.u_id
) t2
left outer join
(
select t3.*,if(t3.u_id <> @p1 ,@rn1:=1,@rn1:=@rn1+1) rn,@p1:=t3.u_id from t3 ,(select @rn1:=0,@p1:=0) rn1 order by t3.u_id
) t3 on t3.u_id = t2.u_id   and t2.rn  = t3.rn  
union all
select t2.u_id as t2id, t2.temp as t2temp, t3.u_id as t3uid,t3.office as t3office 
from
(
select t2.*,if(t2.u_id <> @p ,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,@p:=t2.u_id from t2 ,(select @rn:=0,@p:=0) rn order by t2.u_id
) t2
right outer join
(
select t3.*,if(t3.u_id <> @p1 ,@rn1:=1,@rn1:=@rn1+1) rn,@p1:=t3.u_id from t3 ,(select @rn1:=0,@p1:=0) rn1 order by t3.u_id
) t3 on t3.u_id = t2.u_id   and t2.rn = t3.rn
where t2.rn is null
) z on t1.u_id = t2id or t1.u_id = t3uid 
order by t1.u_id    

+------+-------+--------+----------+
| u_id | name  | t2temp | t3office |
+------+-------+--------+----------+
|   10 | ram   |   NULL |       56 |
|   10 | ram   |     32 |       57 |
|   10 | ram   |     25 |       60 |
|   12 | peter |     32 |       57 |
|   20 | sat   |     42 |       56 |
+------+-------+--------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thanks.. i can get the result..the issue is In table1 u_id(10) occurs only once but in table2 u_id(10) occurs 2times and column temp has two different value for u_id(10) and in table table3 u_id occurs 3times so the output im getting has the result set count 2*3=6 for u_id(10).. correct result should be the count of 3 and not 6 for u_id(10)..how to make this happen.  thanks,

Comment: Great help thanks.. now i have to concatenate strings in two column into a single column and it should be distinct.,based on u_id..(i.e)
| u_id | name  | 
+------+-------+
|   10 | ram~32-25   |                                                                                                        and it is for oracle.... it will be a great help,waiting for your reply    Thanks.

Comment: Im using LISTAGG function and getting the output.. but cant able to meet my requirement of concatenate 2 columns.. please try to resolve tis issue.

Comment: Sorry I don't know Oracle. I suggest you raise a new question.